# Turning a Large Matrix into a Grayscale Image

Tags: python, image, matrix, grayscale

I have a NumPy array of 3,076,568 binary values (1s and 0s). I would like to convert this to a matrix, and then to a grayscale image in Python.

However, when I try to reshape the array into a 1,538,284 x 1,538,284 matrix, I get a memory error.

How can I reduce the size of the matrix so that it will turn into an image that will fit on a screen without losing the uniqueness/data?

Furthermore, how would I turn it into a grayscale image?

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Er... 3,076,568 values would be a ~1754x1754 image, not a 1,538,284x1,538,284 image.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your array of "binary values" is an array of bytes?

If so, you can do (using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/)) after resizing it:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(arr)
```

And then `im.show()` to see it.

If your array has only 0's and 1's (1-bit depth or b/w) you may have to multiply it to 255

```
im = Image.fromarray(arr * 255)
```

Here an example:

```
>>> arr = numpy.random.randint(0,256, 100*100) #example of a 1-D array
>>> arr.resize((100,100))
>>> im = Image.fromarray(arr)
>>> im.show()
```

[image: Random image]

Edit (2018):

This question was written in 2011 and Pillow changed ever since requiring to use the `mode='L'` parameter when loading with `fromarray`.

Also on comments below it was said `arr.astype(np.uint8)` was needed as well, but I have not tested it

Comment: I'm getting an error "Cannot handle this data type" when trying the example above. I needed to pass mode="L" like:  im = Image.fromarray(arr, mode="L")

Comment: @barbolo mine didn't raise an error, it just made the whole picture white. But using mode "L" fixed it, thanks!

Comment: I had to use `arr.astype(np.uint8)` and `mode='L'` (as mentioned above) to get the correct output (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290668/image-fromarray-just-produces-black-image).

Answer (score 12):

Using PIL is not really needed, you can plot the array directly with pyplot (see below).  To save to a file, you could use `plt.imsave('fname.png', im)`.

[image]

Code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = (np.random.rand(1754**2) < 0.5).astype(int)

im = x.reshape(1754, 1754)
plt.gray()
plt.imshow(im)
```

You can also use `plt.show(im)` to display image in new window.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so with [`scipy.misc.toimage`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.toimage.html) and `im.save("foobar.png")`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# your data is "array" - I just made this for testing
width, height = 512, 100
import numpy as np
array = (np.random.rand(width*height) < 0.5).astype(int)
array = array.reshape(height, width)

# what you need
from scipy.misc import toimage

im = toimage(array)
im.save("foobar.png")
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: As of scipy 1.0.0 this function is deprecated. You should use Image.fromarray instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have as example a txt file in your PC with some data (an image), in order to visualize such data as gray scale image you can use this:

```
with open("example.txt", "r") as f:
data = [i.strip("\n").split() for i in f.readlines()]
data1 = np.array(data, dtype=float)
plt.figure(1)
plt.gray()
plt.imshow(data1)
plt.show()
```