# Convert image to ndarray and vice-versa

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have this image and following python code. [image: black and white]

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("File.png")
image = image.convert("1")
image.show()
bw = np.asarray(image).copy()
im01 = np.where(bw, 0, 1)
new_img = Image.fromarray(im01)
new_img.show()
```

[image: new image]

Since the image is black and white, I could see the im01 as a 2D `ndarray` with 0s and 1 as white and black pixels in 184x184 matrix.

Why didn't `Image.fromarray()` work?
Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: The image isn't black and white (bilevel), rather its RGBA!! See if that helps you solve the problem

Comment: I have converted the image to bilevel, and it still doesn't work? (updated the code)

Comment: I think you are running in a similar problem to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290668/image-fromarray-just-produces-black-image

This should be checkable by multiplying your array with 255.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexanderMayer, I think your hint should work for me. Let me try out that!