# converting an Image into numpy array, then save into txt file, then again converting .txt in image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have three stages:
1. convert an Image into numpy array
2. save that array in a text file
3. convert the array into Image by reading that text file

I tried below code, which is converting image into an array and again reading the same array from the text file

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy
im = Image.open("a.jpg") # img size (480,910,3)

np_im = numpy.array(im)

with open('test.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for slice_2d in np_im:
        numpy.savetxt(outfile, slice_2d)

new_data = numpy.loadtxt('test.txt')

new_data=new_data.reshape((480,910,3))

img = Image.fromarray(new_data,'RGB')
img.save('my.bmp')
img.show()
```

if i compare the array (before saving and after loading from file and reshaping) array looks exactly the same(except dot). ex.

```
[[[ 48  58  24]
  [ 48  58  24]
  [ 47  57  23]
... 
and 
[[[ 48.  58.  24.]
  [ 48.  58.  24.]
  [ 47.  57.  23.]
  ...
```

but the image I'm getting is completely distorted. why so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image.fromarray just produces black image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290668/image-fromarray-just-produces-black-image)

Answer (score 1):

after some exercise, I got my answer

```
img = Image.fromarray(new_data.astype(numpy.uint8),'RGB')
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [`numpy.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html). It sounds a lot like you're trying to build this.

There's also a complementary [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

If you feed savetxt a filename ending in `.gz`, it'll even compress the data. loadtxt understands it just the same.

This will work for arbitrary numpy arrays.