# Python: Using Image PIL to show an image returns a black square

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm having a hard time with PIL library as what I see on my screen using plt.imshow(my_img_as_array) is always different from Image.fromarray(my_img_from_array).

More importantly, I'm plotting my image using plt.imshow and it gives me the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX3Rk.png)

However, when I plot it using Image.fromarray it get this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI8Cg.png)

Could anyone help me understand what is going on? Does it have anything to do with transparency?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290668/image-fromarray-just-produces-black-image) question help?

Comment: use plt.savefig('foo.png') and the load as Image.open with PILlow

Comment: try mode='L' in  Image.fromarray(my_img_from_array mode='RGBA') or Image.fromarray(img.astype('uint8'), mode='RGB') changing the mode according to https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

Comment: can you upload the array too ?